# Use Javascript to write names that don't appear in master list to div with id

Tags: javascript

Working demo at http://verlager.com/pairing.php uses `document.write()` but I would prefer to write to a div's ID. I have tried several methods but I can't get the for loop to write to div with id of "textDiv".

```
<script>

function newly_minted() {

var res = "Attaya, James J|Blazak, Stephen A|Cavanaugh, Michael P|Decker, Howard|";

document.getElementById("textDiv").textContent = res;

}

newly_minted();

</script>

<div id="textDiv" style="background:green; color:fff; display:table; height:10rem; width:40rem; margin:4rem auto; clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please explain how what you want relates to what you've written. The especially confusing part is why you take a string and split it, instead of just creating an array, and how that string is supposed to do anything if the name is not `{}`.

Comment: The delimited string is a list of players from http://verlager.com I register players there and press done! and the pairing sheet module loads  http://verlager.com/pairing.php I compare the delimited list and filter out the ones who we have no info on in the master list. Then I use the form to manually add (push) the odd players to the pairing list including the rating info. Then I redisplay the pairing list. The problem is ... the names are still shown in the odd player list even after I added them with the js push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For original post:

This code replaces `textDiv` content because of the simple assignment used:

```
    var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    div.textContent = resort;
    var text = div.textContent; //should append not replace!
```

Try the '+=' operator instead:

```
    var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    div.textContent += resort;
    var text = div.textContent; //should append not replace!
```

---

For the updated post:

1. Declare `newly_minted` before calling it from a different script element. Hoisting function declarations only applies to the script element in which the function is declared.
2. Replace `$( resort)` with `resort` (and split `resort` on `"|"` as in the original). The trailing `"|"` is not altered in this demonstration:

```js
function newly_minted() {

var res = "Attaya, James J|Blazak, Stephen A|Cavanaugh, Michael P|Decker, Howard|".split('|');

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
    var resort = res[i] + " &#9679; ";

    $( "#textDiv" ).append(resort); 
}}

newly_minted();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDiv"></div>
```

Alternatively, without using jQuery, preparing text content first and removing trailing dots:

```js
function newly_minted() {
    var res = "Attaya, James J|Blazak, Stephen A|Cavanaugh, Michael P|Decker, Howard|".split('|');

    for (var i = 0, text =""; i < res.length; i++) { 
        text += res[i] + " \u25cf ";
    }
    text = text.replace(" \u25cf  \u25cf ", ""); // remove two trailing dots
    document.getElementById("textDiv").textContent = text;
}

newly_minted();
```

```html
<div id="textDiv"></div>
```

Comment: The names never get listed with that code (although I am sure it is correct), http://verlager.com/ click the folder to load names, click done!  and view source line 177 of http://verlager.com/pairing.php. Your excellent code is there ... but the players' names of those not found are not listed. Why is that?

Comment: That link won't serve the page to my browser. Seems it's only designed for GoIogle Chrome. It then insulted me by redirecting to the Chrome download page (I have Chrome installed).  It's also off site and not a minimal test page that demonstrates the problem. Please see help center articles [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check the console and fix errors reported. Amongst them,  `newly_minted` is missing a closing curly brace and did not compile. Also **don't use `document.write`  after the page has finished loading** - it will start a new document and destroy the existing page (this is in reference to `validateForm` calling `newlyMinted)`. And again, **please do not just post links to problematic code on your site** - if you fix it, or the link dies, the question is no longer useful to readership.

Comment: I edited the code to make it simpler to parse and understand.